# Will a heavier or lighter tank shell / bullet/ etc. travel further given the same starting energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, projectile

Let's say I have for example two tank shells, both being the same size and having the same shape.

Let's say the starting energy is 100kg*m/s^2, and the one shell is 1kg, the other 25kg.

1kg * 10m/s^2 = 100kg * m/s^2, so the lightweight one travels at ~10m/s

25kg * 2m/s^2 = 100kg ... so the heavyweight one travels 1/5 as fast at 2m/s.

However, momentum = m*s, which means the heavier object has 2.5 times as much momentum as the lighter object.

Does this mean the heavier object will travel further given the same starting energy, or does the greater inertia of the heavier object cancel out all benefit of increased momentum?

Comment: Hint: You used a formula to figure out how _fast_ you can make each projectile go. Next step is to figure out how the starting speed relates to distance traveled. Those shells aren't going to go very far if you fire them into the sand, but if you point the gun above the horizon, they will follow _[ballistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistics)_ trajectories.

Answer (score 2):

The lighter one will travel further. (unless it is ridiculously light like 0.1g or something like that)

Gravity means that the higher the initial velocity the further it will travel.

Think about how gravity effects motion.

Imagine throwing a tennis ball at 10 m/s and a softball/baseball/hockeyball (4 times as heavy) at 5 m/s - which would go further?

Comment: Re, "unless it is ridiculously light." What you're talking about there is the effect of air resistance on a ballistic trajectory. The lighter the projectile, the more the air resistance matters.

Comment: @jameslarge - sorry for delay to your comment. - Yes - air resistance would stop the bullet if it was ridiculously light.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but here's another answer for anyone who wants further clarification.

As stated, the bullet with less mass will travel further. This is because of the formula for kinetic energy KE $= \frac12mv^2$. If KE remains the same for both bullets, and mass is less for one, the velocity must be greater for it for the equation to remain true. Thus, because it has a greater velocity, it will travel  a greater distance.

However, neither momentum nor energy equations will solve this problem (unless the bullet is fired at an upward angle, and you want to find out how high it will travel). Instead, use the kinematic equations.